# Using argparse to accept only one group of required arguments

Tags: argparse

I'm trying to use `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser` for a lil program I write.

The program accepts as an input `EITHER` `(` a path to a txt file `)` `OR` `(`opt1 `&&` opt2 `&&` opt3 `)`.

Meaning if the user wants to use a txt file as an input he cant provide neither of `opt` and if he provided any `opt` - he have to provide all 3 and cant provide `a path to a txt file`.

I tried using `add_mutually_exclusive_group` but not sure how to because the second group of arguments is a group itself.

This is what I tried so far:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='this is the description',)

root_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

group_list = root_group.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group_list.add_argument('-path', help='path to the txt file')

group_list = root_group.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group_list.add_argument('-opt1', help='opt1')
group_list.add_argument('-opt2', help='opt2')
group_list.add_argument('-opt3', help='opt3')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

-

```
python tests.py -path txt -opt1 asdasd
usage: tests.py [-h] [[-path PATH] [-opt1 OPT1 | -opt2 OPT2 | -opt3 OPT3]
tests.py: error: argument -opt1: not allowed with argument -path
```

`path` is not allowed with any of `opt` - that's exactly what I want.

But I want that if the user supplied even 1 `opt` he will have to provide  all of them.

I also want that at least 1 group have be to satisfied.

Comment: Please show what you tried, and explain how it wasn't adequate.

Comment: edited the first post. thanks

Comment: Your title is misleading, then;  you want all or nothing of a set of options.

Comment: Yes, But I want only 1 group

Comment: By putting `opt1`, `opt2` and `opt3` in the `same mulually_exclusive_group`, you guarantee that only one of them can be chosen.

Comment: It is pointless to put `path` in its own `mutually_exclusive_group`.

Answer (score 2):

Mutually exclusive groups aren't designed for nesting.  It accepts it your code, but the net effect into make a 4 arguments exclusive.  It will accept only one of `path`, `opt1`, `opt2`, etc.

While I have explored defining nesting groups, and allowing `any` or `and` operations within groups, such a feature is a long way off.

Since your user has to provide all 3 `--opt` I'd suggest condensing that into one argument:

```
root_group.add_argument('--opt', nargs=3)
root_group.add_argument('--path')
```

Usage should look something like

```
usage: tests.py [-h]  [--path PATH | --opt OPT OPT OPT]
```

Contrast that with a hypothetical usage that allows `nested inclusive groups`:

```
[-path PATH | [-opt1 OPT1 & -opt2 OPT2 & -opt3 OPT3]]
```

===========

With a tuple metavar, the usage can be refined to:

```
g.add_argument('--opt',nargs=3,metavar=('OPT1','OPT2','OPT3'))

usage: ipython3 [-h] [--path PATH | --opt OPT1 OPT2 OPT3]
```

=============

Your other option is to write a custom `usage` and perform you own logical tests after parsing.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a subcommand parser instead. Your "options" aren't really optional; they are 3 required arguments in a particular context.

```
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
sp = p.add_subparsers()

p1 = sp.add_parser('file')
p1.add_argument('path')

p2 = sp.add_parser('opts')
p2.add_argument('opt1')
p2.add_argument('opt2')
p2.add_argument('opt3')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then you would invoke your script with

```
python tmp.py file foo.txt
```

or

```
python tmp.py opts 1 2 3
```

The help will tell you about the required positional argument whose value is either `file` or `opts`:

```
% python tmp.py -h
usage: tmp.py [-h] {file,opts} ...

positional arguments:
  {file,opts}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
```

and each subcommand has its own usage message:

```
% python tmp.py file -h
usage: tmp.py file [-h] path

positional arguments:
  path

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
% python tmp.py opts -h
usage: tmp.py opts [-h] opt1 opt2 opt3

positional arguments:
  opt1
  opt2
  opt3

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```